# Disable anchor tag if href is Empty in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback, unbind

I have an ASP.NET Menu which generates many anchor tags when rendered.
My requirements were

1. to prevent postback if href or an
   anchor tag is "" or "#".
2. to make the cursor not to show the
   hand

First I checked the markup of one of the generated anchor tags

```
    <a href="#" 
        class="popout level1 static" 
        tabindex="-1"  
        onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$NavigationMenu','Unternehmen')">
        Company
    </a>
```

I saw an already bound click event and wrote a quick jquery snippet.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".menu a").each(function () {
            var anchor = $(this);
            var url = (anchor.attr('href').length == 0) ? "" : anchor.attr('href').trim();
            if (url == "" || url == "#") {
                //unbind the __dopostback
                anchor.unbind('click');
                anchor.bind('click',function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                anchor.css("cursor", "default");
            }
        });
    });
```

When I hovered on the empty link, the cursor is showing the default one instead of hand, that means my anchor is recognized. But when I clicked the anchor, postback occurred!

Tried replacing `anchor.unbind('click');` with `anchor.kill('click');`
Tried replacing `e.preventDefault();` by appending `e.stopPropogation` and even `return false;`
Tried replacing `anchor.bind('click', function(e){` with `anchor.click(function(e) {`

Nothing seems to work. What could be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `anchor.removeAttr("onclick");` in your code

Comment: it worked. thanks alot :) and for the love of god! isn't unbinding an event the correct way to go?

Comment: one is Event Property and the other DOM Event, both do the same thing, unfortunately they don't have to point to the same handlers

Comment: who downvoted this answer? thats very very unfair. @ivanov:i have already upvoted.

Comment: @FarligOpptreden: i didn't tell you did.:)

Comment: I didn't say you said I did... I was just saying I upvoted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing eventhandler why not use this simple lines of code.

Actually I want to disable my link in view mode of page.
It worked for me.

In Code-behind:

```
href.Attributes.Clear();
href.Disabled = true;
```

In source-code:

```
<a href="#" id="href" runat="server" onclick="Showpopup();" style="azimuth:left;" >Create New</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about looping through the anchors with an empty href or "#" href only.

```
$(".menu a[href='#'], .menu a[href='']").unbind('click').css("cursor", "default");
```

**EDIT:**

Seems `.unbind` will only unbind events that you have bound using the `.bind` method :/

`.removeAttr` is is :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the event handler, why not explicitly replace it with something along the lines of:

```
anchor.click(function() { return false; });
```

Comment: that will just add a click function wont it?

Comment: It will, but I guess it's worth a shot to see what happens. :)

Comment: -1 read the question carefully. is it not written that I have tried that?

Comment: Oops, soz... Seems like I missed that last sentence... :P

Comment: Thank you SIR! Will do SIR! (edit: no sarcasm intended, promise)

Comment: Wha?! Where did you see that?!